# Flutter's MediaQuery rectangle seems incorrect

Tags: flutter

A `Rect` with a top-left at (0, 0) and sized `MediaQuery.of(context).size` should match *exactly* the rectangle left after the `AppBar` rectangle is present.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF80EFEF)),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('MyApp'),
            ),
            body: MyWidget()));
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var deviceData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return CustomPaint(painter: MyPainter(appSize: deviceData.size));
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  Size appSize;
  MyPainter({this.appSize});
    
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()..color = Colors.indigo;

    const double margin1 = 70;
    canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromLTWH(margin1, margin1, appSize.width - 2 * margin1,
            appSize.height - 2 * margin1),
        paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

As you see here:

[image: MediaQuery rectangle protrudes]

it does not. It protrudes (when targeting `chrome`) from the bottom. We're only able to see that when we use a margin to reduce the rectangle's size.

Why does the rectangle not match the expected area? Is this a bug?

Comment: i dont know why you need that `MediaQuery` if you have `Size size` here: `paint(Canvas canvas, Size size)`

Comment: @pskink Yes, exactly. I also was expecting it would be redundant/excessive to make a `MediaQuery` when I'm anyway using `CustomPainter`. But as you see from the two filled rectangles, the two rectangles are very different. Explaining the difference between them goes some way towards finding the top-left and bottom-right returned by `CustomPainter` to the `StatelessWidget` that creates it.

Comment: ok, so what exactly do you want to achieve? to know the exact size of your `Canvas`? if so, `size` is your friend

Comment: @pskink cool.. so.. exactly: I have a simple path drawing, say a sine wave defined in [-2π, 4π] × [-1, 1]. I want to draw this elementary path to fill the available size (after the `AppBar` takes its space). Hence I want to compute the `Transform` that takes the `Rect` in which the sine wave arises, to the `Rect` of the `CustomPainter`. The first step is to find that `Rect`, but the value obtained in `void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size)` is _in_-correct.

Comment: @pskink `CustomPaint` may indeed be exactly what will solve the problem (if it does query the child widget and adjusts the transformation accordingly). I wrote a draft answer. Can you see what needs fixing, and confirm that `CustomPainter` does indeed solve the problem?

Comment: @pskink Okay.. zeroing in.. but not quite there.. Updated the working answer.

Comment: @pskink No! We can't modify the coordinates where the circle and other objects are drawn! Think of it this way: we have very many objects, all drawn in some coordinate system. We're working, say, in the complex plane, and so we can't use the coordinate system of the canvas. We must use [-1, 1] times [-1, 1]. How do we map _that_ rectangle to the visible rectangle?

Comment: @pskink We can do the mapping "manually" (via a `Transform` object). In that case we need to know what we're mapping to. Or we can use a widget that does the transformation for us. If `CustomPaint` does it, it's not clear how.

Comment: "We'd like to see all four quadrants (and see the circle fill the available space)." - i have no idea what you really want then... maybe some image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231621/discussion-between-sam-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink I added an image. Not sure if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use layoutbuilder to know the exact remaining space left.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('LayoutBuilder Example')),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return Text('Width: ${constraints.maxWidth} Height: ${constraints.maxHeight}');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: With layout builder it will check the remaining space that is left checking with his parent widget and not the complete resolution of your device. You can check with my example if you make your screen smaller or bigger the values will change and if you put it in a smaller parent the values will also change to it's parent remaining space. You can find the documentation with examples in: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html

Comment: I see the issue. Is it all right if I edit your answer to explain a bit what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

When we write a `Widget` class such as

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var deviceData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return CustomPaint(painter: MyPainter(appSize: deviceData.size));
  }
}
```

and make a `MediaQuery.of()`, the `context` that we are querying is not that of `MyWidget`. It is the context of the parent of `MyWidget` in the widget objects tree.

In this case the parent is the `Scaffold`. Hence the `context` we get **does include** the `AppBar`!

(To make it clearer, it would perhaps be more apt to write `parentContext`, rather than `context`.)

The solution is to add an intermediate "dummy" parent widget that has the correct dimensions.

This does not need to be a full-fledged new class. Using either `Builder` or `LayoutBuilder` is enough.

Using `Builder` doesn't cut it (why?)

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: new ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF80EFEF)),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('MyApp'),
            ),
            body: Builder(
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context) {
                    return MyWidget();
              },
            )));
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var deviceData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return CustomPaint(painter: MyPainter(appSize: deviceData.size));
  }
}
```

Hence we need to use, as in Ayad's answer, `LayoutBuilder`.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: new ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF80EFEF)),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('MyApp'),
            ),
            body: LayoutBuilder(
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, constraints) {
                    return MyWidget(size: Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight));
              },
            )));
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Size size;
  MyWidget({this.size}) {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(painter: MyPainter(appSize: size));
  }
}
```

We then see that we have the correct `Size`.

[image: we have the correct size]

Comment: you dont need any `LayoutBuilder` - 
all you need is `Size size` parameter passed to `paint` method

Comment: @pskink As you wish. From my perspective your solution has an insufficient separation of concerns. `FooCirclePainter` should not know, nor care, where it's drawn. It only knows, and only computes objects, for and in its own coordinate system. That's why a cleaner solution is to insert a `Transform` widget wrapper, and to compute the `Matrix4` object needed to perform the transformation. All that is done in `FooCircle`. `FooCirclePainter` has one size only, its own, not that of the canvas where it will be drawn.

Comment: @pskink To see that this is better, consider a case where you need to visualize `FooCirclePainter` in many windows, each with its own size. At all time there should be just one `FooCirclePainter` that's shared. It is the different wrapper `Transform` objects that are different.

Comment: @pskink Think of it this way: you don't have a hundred, but a hundred thousand, points. The hardware of your users, even if modest, is perfectly able to draw them interactively. But you've taken that speed away. You're building the points from scratch every time. Instead, get `FooCirclePainter` to create a `Path`. You build that `Path` only once, without depending on the size.

Comment: @pskink A couple of issues: - You're not building a Path object (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path-class.html). - You don't need to call `fold()` and compute min/max. `Path` has a method `getBounds()`. - If you iterate to translate by (xmin, ymin), then, as you observed, you're using a linear computation on the CPU, rather than a pipeline operation on the GPU.

Comment: @pskink The right way is to implement a reusable Widget, one that encapsulates the scale and translate Transformation for any kind of child widget—after asking it for its min/max `Rect`. That's basically what the Image widget does, but for only one kind of child widget. Such a widget may already exist in Flutter—I'm not sure yet. Somebody should probably ask this as a targeted question.

Comment: @pskink You're suggesting, I think, that a `FitRectWithinWidget` widget would be overkill. Perhaps, but notice that the `Image` widget does a bit more than this. It would be a coincidence for the `from` and `to` `Rect`s to have the same aspect ratio, and so it's necessary to write `return from.aspectRatio > to.aspectRatio ? expressionA : expressionB;` with an extension defining `aspectRatio` as `size.width/size.height`. `expressionA` and `expressionB` are identical when the two aspect ratios are identical.

Comment: @pskink As someone wise once said: "talk is cheap. show me the code." By that here I mean that unless we are talking about a specific code sample, we can't really say anything precise. In the present discussion notice that there are two issues at play. First, the resolution of the device. If a user has a very high DPI, then yes, we do want the line thickness to increase (or else the line may not be perceptible).

Comment: @pskink Second, for any scaling, it very much matters whether the rendering (i.e. scan conversion) is happening before or after the scaling. If a diagonal line is first rasterized and _then_ scaled, the edges will, as you have observed, be ugly, regardless of whether anti-aliasing is performed.

Comment: @pskink Let's throw a big party and invite a crowd . https://stackoverflow.com/q/67327988/700648